# How can I have a Golang script modify a value in my Terraform (HCL format) file?

Tags: go, terraform, hcl

I am attempting to do a small bit of automation on a Terraform file I have, that defines an Azure Network Security Group. Essentially I have a website & SSH access that I only want to allow to my public IP address, which I can obtain from `icanhazip.com`. I am hoping to write my IP into the relevant part of the .tf file with a Golang script (essentially set the value for `security_rule.source_address_prefixes`).

I am attempting to use `hclsimple` library in Golang, as well as having tried `gohcl`, `hclwrite` and others, but I'm not getting anywhere with converting the HCL file into Golang structs, essentially.

My Terraform file (HCL format I believe) is as follows:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "my_nsg" {
  name                = "my_nsg"
  location            = "loc"
  resource_group_name = "rgname"

  security_rule       = [
           {
               access                                     = "Deny"
               description                                = "Desc"
               destination_address_prefix                 = "*"
               destination_address_prefixes               = []
               destination_application_security_group_ids = []
               destination_port_range                     = ""
               destination_port_ranges                    = [
                   "123",
                   "456",
                   "789",
                   "1001",
                ]
               direction                                  = "Inbound"
               name                                       = "AllowInboundThing"
               priority                                   = 100
               protocol                                   = "*"
               source_address_prefix                      = "*"
               source_address_prefixes                    = [
                  # obtain from icanhazip.com
                  "1.2.3.4"
               ]
               source_application_security_group_ids      = []
               source_port_range                          = "*"
               source_port_ranges                         = []
            },
           {
               access                                     = "Allow"
               description                                = "Grant acccess to App"
               destination_address_prefix                 = "*"
               destination_address_prefixes               = []
               destination_application_security_group_ids = []
               destination_port_range                     = ""
               destination_port_ranges                    = [
                   "443",
                   "80",
                ]
               direction                                  = "Inbound"
               name                                       = "AllowIPInBound"
               priority                                   = 200
               protocol                                   = "*"
               source_address_prefix                      = ""
               source_address_prefixes                    = [
                # obtain from icanhazip.com
                   "1.2.3.4"
                ]
               source_application_security_group_ids      = []
               source_port_range                          = "*"
               source_port_ranges                         = []
            }
        ]
}
```

And this is as far as I have got with my Golang script, in attempting to represent the above data as structs, and then decoding the .tf file itself (I copied a couple of methods locally from `hclsimple` in order to have it decode a .tf file, as suggested in their docs.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/gohcl"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclsimple"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/hclsyntax"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2/json"
)

type Config struct {
    NetworkSecurityGroup []NetworkSecurityGroup `hcl:"resource,block"`
}

type NetworkSecurityGroup struct {
    Type              string         `hcl:"azurerm_network_security_group,label"`
    Name              string         `hcl:"mick-linux3-nsg,label"`
    NameAttr          string         `hcl:"name"`
    Location          string         `hcl:"location"`
    ResourceGroupName string         `hcl:"resource_group_name"`
    SecurityRule      []SecurityRule `hcl:"security_rule,block"`
}

type SecurityRule struct {
    Access                                 string   `hcl:"access"`
    Description                            string   `hcl:"description"`
    DestinationAddressPrefix               string   `hcl:"destination_address_prefix"`
    DestinationAddressPrefixes             []string `hcl:"destination_address_prefixes"`
    DestinationApplicationSecurityGroupIds []string `hcl:"destination_application_security_group_ids"`
    DestinationPortRange                   string   `hcl:"destination_port_range"`
    DestinationPortRanges                  []string `hcl:"destination_port_ranges"`
    Direction                              string   `hcl:"direction"`
    Name                                   string   `hcl:"name"`
    Priority                               int      `hcl:"priority"`
    Protocol                               string   `hcl:"protocol"`
    SourceAddressPrefix                    string   `hcl:"source_address_prefix"`
    SourceAddressPrefixes                  []string `hcl:"source_address_prefixes"`
    SourceApplicationSecurityGroupIds      []string `hcl:"source_application_security_group_ids"`
    SourcePortRange                        string   `hcl:"source_port_range"`
    SourcePortRanges                       []string `hcl:"source_port_ranges"`
}

func main() {
    // lets pass this in as a param?
    configFilePath := "nsg.tf"

    // create new Config struct
    var config Config

    // This decodes the TF file into the config struct, and hydrates the values
    err := MyDecodeFile(configFilePath, nil, &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to load configuration: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Configuration is %#v", config)

    // let's read in the file contents
    file, err := os.Open(configFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to read file: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Read the file and output as a []bytes
    bytes, err := io.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading file:", err)
        return
    }

    // Parse, decode and evaluate the config of the .tf file
    hclsimple.Decode(configFilePath, bytes, nil, &config)

    // iterate through the rules until we find one with
    // Description = "Grant acccess to Flask App"

    // CODE GO HERE
    for _, nsg := range config.NetworkSecurityGroup {
        fmt.Printf("security rule: %s", nsg.SecurityRule)
    }
}

// Basically copied from here https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/v2.16.2/hclsimple/hclsimple.go#L59
// but modified to handle .tf files too
func MyDecode(filename string, src []byte, ctx *hcl.EvalContext, target interface{}) error {
    var file *hcl.File
    var diags hcl.Diagnostics

    switch suffix := strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(filename)); suffix {
    case ".tf":
        file, diags = hclsyntax.ParseConfig(src, filename, hcl.Pos{Line: 1, Column: 1})
    case ".hcl":
        file, diags = hclsyntax.ParseConfig(src, filename, hcl.Pos{Line: 1, Column: 1})
    case ".json":
        file, diags = json.Parse(src, filename)
    default:
        diags = diags.Append(&hcl.Diagnostic{
            Severity: hcl.DiagError,
            Summary:  "Unsupported file format",
            Detail:   fmt.Sprintf("Cannot read from %s: unrecognized file format suffix %q.", filename, suffix),
        })
        return diags
    }
    if diags.HasErrors() {
        return diags
    }

    diags = gohcl.DecodeBody(file.Body, ctx, target)
    if diags.HasErrors() {
        return diags
    }
    return nil
}

// Taken from here https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl/blob/v2.16.2/hclsimple/hclsimple.go#L89
func MyDecodeFile(filename string, ctx *hcl.EvalContext, target interface{}) error {
    src, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            return hcl.Diagnostics{
                {
                    Severity: hcl.DiagError,
                    Summary:  "Configuration file not found",
                    Detail:   fmt.Sprintf("The configuration file %s does not exist.", filename),
                },
            }
        }
        return hcl.Diagnostics{
            {
                Severity: hcl.DiagError,
                Summary:  "Failed to read configuration",
                Detail:   fmt.Sprintf("Can't read %s: %s.", filename, err),
            },
        }
    }
    return MyDecode(filename, src, ctx, target)
}
```

When I run the code, essentially I am struggling to define NetworkSecurityGroup.SecurityRule, and receive the following error with the above code:

```
2023/05/24 11:42:11 Failed to load configuration: nsg.tf:6,3-16: Unsupported argument; An argument named "security_rule" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "security_rule"?
exit status 1
```

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: I am unsure what the end goal is here, but would the CDKTF for Go achieve the same overall objective you are working towards?

Comment: I think for this sort of need you should abandon the idea of trying to load this into struct types with tags and instead use the `hclwrite` API directly, because then you can make surgical changes to the existing configuration without losing information such as comments, and without having to fully model the Terraform language in your own code.

Comment: My recommendation would be to factor out your IP address into a local value (inside a `locals` block) and then use `hclwrite`'s API directly -- without `hclsimple` or `gohcl` or any other wrapping abstractions -- to overwrite the relevant entry in the `locals` block.

Comment: The parts of the `hclwrite` API you'd use here are `Body.Blocks` to iterate over the blocks until you find the one you want to modify, and then `Body.SetAttributeValue` on that block's body to overwrite the local value containing your IP address.

Comment: Alternatively you could try to achieve your desired result using this existing third-party tool, which is a wrapper around the `hclwrite` API: https://github.com/minamijoyo/hcledit

Comment: Thanks. Yeah my code is pretty bloated / confusing, due to all the different attempts i've tried. happy to scale back and start from scratch again, and just try and leverage `hclwrite` (although i think, from memory, it's not happy with me trying to work with a .tf file...) I'll report back.

Comment: (i should point out this code does work on a simpler .tf example, so although it is convoluted it did work! it does not like the structure of the `azurerm_network_security_group` however )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not currently possible with https://github.com/minamijoyo/hcledit (see here https://github.com/minamijoyo/hcledit/issues/50 - this suggests that `hclwrite` itself would need a change to facilitate)

So I've worked around as suggested by @Martin Atkins:

I've created a single `locals.tf` file containing a locals variable, which I then reference in the NSG security rules:

```
locals {
    my_ip = "1.2.3.4"
}
```

and now I simply obtain my IP and use sed to update the value in the locals.tf file

```
my_ip=$(curl -s -4 icanhazip.com)
sed -i "s|my_ip = \".*\"|my_ip = \"$my_ip\"|" locals.tf
```

Answer (score 0):

slice should be represented as

```
security_rule { item1 }
security_rule { item2 }
```

instead of

```
security_rule = [{ item1 }, { item2 }]
```

in HCL.

There is also a new HCL unmarshaler: https://github.com/genelet/determined/.

The result from "determined" is:

```
&main.Config{NetworkSecurityGroup:[]main.NetworkSecurityGroup{main.NetworkSecurityGroup{Type:"azurerm_network_security_group", Name:"my_nsg", NameAttr:"my_nsg", Location:"loc", ResourceGroupName:"rgname", SecurityRule:[]main.SecurityRule{main.SecurityRule{Access:"Deny", Description:"Desc", DestinationAddressPrefix:"*", DestinationAddressPrefixes:[]string{}, DestinationApplicationSecurityGroupIds:[]string{}, DestinationPortRange:"", DestinationPortRanges:[]string{"123", "456", "789", "1001"}, Direction:"Inbound", Name:"AllowInboundThing", Priority:100, Protocol:"*", SourceAddressPrefix:"*", SourceAddressPrefixes:[]string{"1.2.3.4"}, SourceApplicationSecurityGroupIds:[]string{}, SourcePortRange:"*", SourcePortRanges:[]string{}}, main.SecurityRule{Access:"Allow", Description:"Grant acccess to App", DestinationAddressPrefix:"*", DestinationAddressPrefixes:[]string{}, DestinationApplicationSecurityGroupIds:[]string{}, DestinationPortRange:"", DestinationPortRanges:[]string{"443", "80"}, Direction:"Inbound", Name:"AllowIPInBound", Priority:200, Protocol:"*", SourceAddressPrefix:"", SourceAddressPrefixes:[]string{"1.2.3.4"}, SourceApplicationSecurityGroupIds:[]string{}, SourcePortRange:"*", SourcePortRanges:[]string{}}}}}}
```